Uninstalling ubuntu from my laptop
Ever since i installed  ubuntu from a boot able USB and it erased the original OS from my laptop  everything has been acting up on my lap top so i am having trouble uninstalling it keeps getting me stuck in a boot loop and wont boot anything else from bios. how can i fix this?

You don't uninstall an OS, you just boot your installation media for your new OS & install over the prior OS.  How you boot external media is device specific (esp. related to firmware settings). The OS you have installed is not involved in the initial boot process; the firmware of your device controls that & passes control to the installed OS only after it's followed whatever your settings tell it to do.

Yes you are correct, I'm fairly new to the computer world but i finally figured it out. thank you all for the help I appreciate it.
